# Could not connect: Access denied for user 'indysoft_admin'@'localhost

Tags: php, mysql, sql

ii have made a Mysql database and and user for the same with all permissions Still am getting the following error.

**Could not connect: Access denied for user 'indysoft_admin'@'localhost**

i am using the following connection.php script for connection

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'indysoft_admin','');
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else{

mysql_select_db("indysoft_person", $con);


}
?>
```

Comment: You are passing the user/pass credentials, right?

Comment: Obviously your credentials are not working. How did you create the user? Did you do `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` afterwards?

Comment: The user has no password? Also, don't use mysql_ anymore..

Comment: Off topic, use mysqli_* if it's a new project. mysql_* are deprecated since PHP5.5

Answer (score 1):

You didnt create the User with the same credentials, like your passing. Check your Database for ur username and password. Maybe a misspelling?